# How to implement functionality to specify which parameters to receive when making a get request to Rest API?

Tags: c#, sql, rest, asp.net-web-api

Because i need to reduce load on my API, i thought about implementing a possibility to specify which properties you want to receive on request.

Right now when users make request to api to get a product

```
/api/products/{id}
```

They get whole product information (id, name, Created Date, updatedDate, deleted, active, and so on), so i need to pull all of those properties from the DB.

What i want to achieve is, instead of returning all the properties that a product have from the server, api users could just select which properties they want to receive. URL could look like this:

```
/products/{id}/props={id,name,LastUpdated}
```

so that i need to only select id, name and LastUpdated from the DB to return to the API user.

How to actually implement such a functionality the smartest way?

Comment: You can have 2 models perhaps. Model A with less properties, and model B with more, B of course inherits from A. And you always save B to Database. 
So, the idea is just to make the "contract" with the simple one, model A.

Then on the Controller you can pass A as argument to create B on consructor. You can use a mapping library, reflexion (need to cache it), or hand made mapping.

If you dont like the idea, let me know, i will try to think something better.

Comment: @JuanCarlos  it would work if i just had A simple model and complete model, but what if i would have 20 different possibilities of combinations of properties? than i had to create 20 different models. I thought about implementing a strategy pattern for each possibility, but that again it will be 20 different strategies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDIT: Now question is well described.

I see. This is only possible without a model. (I think)

I think JObject is a good start, it's probably the most tested library for this.

More or less should be like this:

1. Parse querystring
2. Get those fields and select from database. (if using sql server you can have a stored procedure with dynamic query inside.
3. Get result and parse it to json Here is where newtonsoft comes handy.
4. Return Json.

Comment: OData as @ivan-yurchenko posted is also a good idea. Maybe bit more complex to implement but also more robust.

Comment: Odata wouldnt fit in into implementation frame right now. But i could do the same thing by hand using your approach

Comment: @Timsen thanks for marking my proposal as answer. Let me know if you implement it and how you do it.

Answer (score 0):

[**OData**](http://www.odata.org) is what you need. It allows you to specify properties that you need to retreive in the URL and then generate a query to the database that will return only these specific properties.

The basic tutorial (from the official site): http://www.odata.org/getting-started/basic-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this for example, but edited to suite your api needs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{

    public class Man
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var man = new Man
        {
            Id = 2,
            Name = "A Name",
            Phone = "123456789"
        };

        var props = "id,name";

        var customPropsArray = props.Split(',');

        Type t = man.GetType();
        PropertyInfo[] properties = t.GetProperties(
            BindingFlags.NonPublic | // Include protected and private properties
            BindingFlags.Public | // Also include public properties
            BindingFlags.Instance // Specify to retrieve non static properties
            );

        var dynamicObject = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;

        foreach (var p in properties.Where(x => customPropsArray.Contains(x.Name.ToLower())))
        {           
            dynamicObject.Add(p.Name, p.GetValue(man));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OData is a good idea, but if you cannot use that for some reason, you could use an `enum`to specify which properties you want, then serialise them in your API via a `Dictionary` to Json. Something like this:

```
[Flags]
public enum Props
{
    FirstName = 1,
    Surname = 2,
    Address = 4,
    Occupation = 8
}

public string GetValues(int id, Props props)
{
    var items = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    if (props == 0 || props.HasFlag(Props.FirstName))
        items.Add("FirstName", "Bob");

    if (props == 0 || props.HasFlag(Props.Surname))
        items.Add("Surname", "Smith");

    if (props == 0 || props.HasFlag(Props.Address))
        items.Add("Address", "London");

    if (props == 0 || props.HasFlag(Props.Occupation))
        items.Add("Occupation ", "Professional Tea Drinker");

    //Using Newtonsoft Json:
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(items);
}
```

And you call it like this:

```
GetValues(1, (Props)0)
GetValues(1, (Props)1)
GetValues(1, (Props)3)
```

Returns:

> {"FirstName":"Bob","Surname":"Smith","Address":"London","Occupation ":"Professional Tea Drinker"}
>
> {"FirstName":"Bob"}
>
> {"FirstName":"Bob","Surname":"Smith"}